# How do we count the 7 arm tefillin windings?

Tags: tefilin

[This article](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/479863/jewish/Why-is-the-tefillin-wrapped-seven-times.htm) gives several reasons why we wrap the tefillin around our arm 7 times.

Do the 7 windings start from the "half" intial wind that begins from the bottom of the "loop" that the strap comes from, (See the 1st wind in the picture, below) or is that one excluded and does it have to be complete "full circle" windings around the arm?

(In the picture, below, it looks like that 1st one is excluded, as there are another 7. But, I'm not sure if there are different *minhagim* regrading this.

[image: Arm Tefillin]

Comment: I believe Sephardim and yemenites begin their wrapping in the opposite direction, which might also confuse things

Comment: @Aaron http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28489/759

Comment: almost dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13334/759

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1778&st=&pgnum=68&hilite=

Answer (score 2):

The half at the brginning and the half at the end are such that the part that is on the arm at the top is opposite the part that is not on the arm at the bottom and vice versa. Thus only seven wrapping are actually seen on that arm at any one time.  This is from inspection of my arm at Shacharis.

Comment: How do we know your arm accurately represents traditional Jewish practice? Was your arm under certification by a halachic authority?

Comment: @DoubleAA This is how I was taught in Yeshiva and how I see others do it. Consider anybody wrapping the arm. The part that enters the arm and the part that exits the arm to go on the hand.